# Factory Girl: How to create record with has_one_through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following relationships as follows

```
class LoanApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :case_status, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :case_status_bankers, :class_name => 'CaseStatus', :foreign_key => "loan_application_id"
  has_many :banker_assignments, :through => :case_status_bankers, :source => :banker_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class CaseStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loan_application
  has_many :banker_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class BankerAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case_status
  has_one :loan_application, :through => :case_status, :autosave => false
end
```

As you can see, it shows the different relationships within the 3 models. The written factory is as follows

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :loan_application do
    association :case_status

    factory :mortgage_loan do
      product { build_stubbed(:MLF) }
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :case_status do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :banker_assignment do
    association :case_status
    association :loan_application
  end
end
```

When i write the following spec to create a BankerAssignment record, the loan_application_id field always turns up nil and there is no associated loan_application record.

This is my spec code

```
@mortgage_loan = create(:mortgage_loan, product: create(:MLF))
case_status = create(:case_status, loan_application: @mortgage_loan)
@assignment_status = find_or_create(:bank_assignment_status_pending_doc)
@banker_assignment = create(:banker_assignment, banker: @banker, banker_assignment_status: @assignment_status, loan_application: @mortgage_loan)
```

But it seems not be working.

Anyone knows how i write the spec code so that when a banker assignment record is created, it has an associated loan_application.

Thanks